# If I'm safe from CSRF, am I safe from spambots?

Tags: spam-prevention, csrf

I've read up quite a bit on spam prevention, and this is one apparent solution that keeps being suggested:

> Use a token and put it into a session
>   and also add it to the form. If the
>   token is not submitted with the form
>   or doesn't match then it is automated
>   and can be ignored.

Source: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3588/how-do-spambots-work

Which basically is saying to protect yourself from CSRF.

So my question is, do spambots rely entirely on a method that incorporates CSRF? Do they smply send repeat POST requests without actually requesting the page to figure out what the hidden token embedded in the form is? This seems almost suspiciously too easy to stop and I'm skeptical. Anyone have any concrete information on this?

Comment: Different spambots work differently. Most probably work in the way you described, but a lot of them circumvent this technique. In general, any measures you take against spambots can and will be avoided.

Comment: even if it only works against 1% of the spambots out there, that's 1% less of a chance that your site will get hit.

Comment: @jnpcl: Right, and I'm not saying that you shouldn't use any kind of spam prevention; I'm just saying that the assumption that you are automatically "safe from spambots" is dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine crawler that visits random URL and if it sees form, fills it and submits. In this case, token will be automatically accepted, as long as generated on page load.

So, as an additional defense - place tough CAPTCHA.